# iOS associated domain for universal links

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

I recently uploaded a new version of my app to the app store - its live now.  However in my Xcode project I forgot to add my `Associated Domains` in my entitlements to enable Universal Links.  I have now added it to my project, but does this mean I also have to upload a new version of my app to the app store?  Is there any other method I can use to update the related associated domains on my existing live app?

I suspect I have to upload a new version of my app.

Comment: Yes, you will need to update on the App Store. And the links will only start working for users who update to the latest version too.

Comment: @Fogmeister - Thanks.  another question though, on the https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/ its saying `Link to Application: Error no apps associated with url` - once my new version is uploaded will Apple now be aware of the associated domain in my app for all users or just users who have my app....or users who have that version of my app?

Comment: Hmm… not sure about that one. Sorry.

Comment: Turns out I was using the validation tool on my windows/chrome machine.  When I used it on my Mac Safari, it added an additional message I didn't see on windows/chrome.  It states `The entitlement data used to verify deep link dual authentication is from the current released version of your app.  This data may take 48 hours to update`.   This implies that Apple pulls the `Associated Domains` from the current app version to add to its databases for all users - not just users who have your app or that newest version.  Well, thats how I interpret that message.

Comment: That message is only relevant for the validation tool.  The associated domains entitlement is registered on the specific device when the app with the entitlement is installed by the user.  This means that only users who have your updated app installed will have the associated domains functionality